# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto

Tags: python, scraping

Estoy haciendo un web scrap con python 3, entonces cuando intento conectarme al servidor por python usando urllib request de python, me rechaza la conexion diciendome

> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto

Estoy usando un codigo que llevo usando en varios trabajos de este tipo y hasta ahora me iba funcionando

```
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://e-consulta.sunat.gob.pe/cl-at-ittipcam/tcS01Alias'

datos = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(datos.read(), "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

Comment: El host remoto te cierra la conexión después de que la hayas establecido. No es algo que dependa de tu programa, sino del servidor. Quizás has hecho demasiadas peticiones en muy poco tiempo y te han bloqueado por intento de DoS, o por violar alguna política. Quizás el servidor esté inestable (¿funciona desde un navegador?) Probablemente se arregle por si solo si esperas un tiempo

Comment: Me parece que el comentario abufalia puede ser considerado una respuesta en sí, ya que no requieres en realidad cambiar tu código ya que el que rechaza es el servidor que estás leyendo. Lo que podrías hacer es agregar un tiempo de espera con time.sleep() para no saturarlo.